# NSFileModificationDate not correctly set on SMB mount

Tags: cocoa, nsfilemanager, samba, smb

I use [NSFileManager setAttribute](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/setAttributes%3aofItemAtPath%3aerror%3a) to set the modification date for files.

Everything works fine but when I do that on some SMB disks sometimes in a non deterministic manner the date isn't changed.

The code shown below for simplicity doesn't check error but in real code all API calls return success so it's impossible to understand what hell doesn't work

What I do is

- copy files (and subdirectories) from a source folder to a destination folder
- destination folder is a SMB disk
- after a copy I set the modification date for copied file (I change modification date only for files I don't take care of directories)
- some files are correctly updated but some files don't (not always the same)!!!!!!
- different smb disks have different results (eg winxp mount, buffalo)
- my code runs inside a separated thread

The code I use is

```
NSString* srcPath = @"/Volumes/smbtest/folder-1/ATKXP.INF";
NSString* destPath = @"/Volumes/smbtest/folder-2/ATKXP.INF";


NSDictionary* srcAttrs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:srcPath
                                                                          error:nil];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:srcPath
                                        toPath:destPath
                                         error:nil];

NSDictionary* dateAttrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           srcAttrs.fileCreationDate, NSFileCreationDate,
                           srcAttrs.fileModificationDate, NSFileModificationDate,
                           nil];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:dateAttrs
                                 ofItemAtPath:destPath
                                        error:nil];
```

Everything work always correctly on local HFS disks

Comment: You should pass a pointer to a pointer to `NSError` and check the result code. If the result code indicates failure, examine the `NSError` to find out why.

Comment: The posted code doesn't contain error for simplicity, in real code there isn't error, all calls return success, I edit the post to clarify that

Comment: You can try monitoring what's happening using `sudo fs_usage -f filesys -w -p <PID of your program>` to see file operations and any syscall result codes. The docs says `-setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:` "ignores any rejection of an attempted modification" but you should still see it at the syscall level. Also, when it fails, you can try performing the same operation at the shell to see if it works.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6916766/1312143) claims that setting the modification date separately from the creation date is more reliable.

Comment: Splitting create and modification date doesn't change results so now I'm focusing only on modification date and using fs_usage the log shows only to calls relative to copied path: first call to 'getattrlist' and then to 'utimes' but modification date isn't updated

Comment: `fs_usage` should show the syscall result. What is it?

Comment: I prefer to show to you the full log on http://pastebin.com/82GipBku because is easier to describe than on SO. As you can see at line 4 there is the utimes call to set the modification date. I've removed the create date set so we can focus only on modification date

Comment: Doesn't look like there's an error. So the problem seems like it's in either the file system driver or on the server side. I don't know if you're in a position to look at logs on the server. In any case, it seems like it's beyond your control. Either live with the behavior or try putting a check for the attribute value after trying to set it and, if it isn't what you tried to set it to, try again (up to some retry limit).

Comment: I've found a very ugly workaround, setting twice the modification date. The first time I pass a 'now' date then the correct one and it works. I think to check if I'm working on a samba volume using [NSWorkspace getFileSystemInfoForPath] so I do that only if necessary. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like there's an error. So the problem seems like it's in either the file system driver or on the server side. I don't know if you're in a position to look at logs on the server. In any case, it seems like it's beyond your control. Either live with the behavior or try putting a check for the attribute value after trying to set it and, if it isn't what you tried to set it to, try again (up to some retry limit).